# need help printing a table using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the description:
Your program should develop a table of costs, based on the user's inputs of the starting and ending years and the formula. The table should produce columns as seen below, The column Year is the year, starting at the point the user says to start at, and going to the ending year, stopping there. The size of the step in the table is also specified by the user. The user inputs are all integers. Your program can assume that. NOTE: The "ending year, stopping there" phrase is a bit ambiguous. If you want to use the ending year as the stop value in a range function, that is fine. If you want to add one to the ending year and use that as the stop value, that is also ok.

```
Big Blue Hard Drive Storage Cost

Enter the starting year: 1992
Enter the ending year: 2015
What step size for the table? 4

        Hard Drive Storage Costs Table

Start Year = 1992
End Year = 2015

   Year           Cost Per Gigabyte ($)

   1992                  2002.627
   1996                  199.894
   2000                  19.953
   2004                  1.992
   2008                  0.199
   2012                  0.02
```

that is what the output is supposed to look like.

My question is how am i supposed to construct a for loop to do that?

I have everything done, but for my for loop, what am i supposed put for the year? since the input values are only start year, end year and the step size. My code:

```
    for year in range(x > 1979, y < 2011, z):
        cost = 10^(-0.2502 * (year - 1980) + 6.304)

main()
```

This is the equation for the cost: http://prntscr.com/4r9l9j

Comment: Without the rest of your code I don't know what you've named the three user inputs, but note that the arguments to `range` are named `start`, `stop` and `step`...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about deleting stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Simple.

```
for year in range(x, y, z):
    cost = 10**(-0.2502 * (year - 1980) + 6.304)
    print(str(year) + "\t" + str(cost))
```

Comment: the start year, end years and the step size are the input values.

Comment: This formula is based on data from 1980 to 2010. and i got an traceback error: builtins.TypeError: 'float' object is not callable on line 22 and line 27

Comment: Try now. The formula had wrong operators in it.

Comment: The program runs without any error, but it's not printing anything after the loop.

Comment: Are the year and cost values being printed?

Comment: I updated my code in the editor right now. I ran it and nothing after the loop is being printed. "print (year + "\t" + cost)" isn't printing anything.

Comment: Strange. It runs perfectly on my side. I've modified the print a little bit. try now. Please replace the whole for loop.

Comment: ahhh thank you very much!! :) It works now! Except the value shows too many decimal values. But i don't think it should cause too much problems

Comment: Use the `round()` function to round off your answer. Please accept this answer if it helped you. :)